# How do you properly handle exceptions for asynchronous code in Python for NATS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, error-handling, nats.io

#### main.py

```
import asyncio
import signal

from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS

from client.nats_client import NATSClient
from factory.logger import LoggerFactory
from helpers.environment import get_log_level

log = LoggerFactory.get_logger(__name__, log_level=get_log_level())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Using a, low-level asyncio API, to run the CustomClient coroutines"""
    client = NATSClient(nc=NATS())
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.create_task(client.start())
    try:
        event_loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # CTRL-C was pressed by the user
        log.info("CTRL-C was pressed!")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        log.info("cancelled")
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

#### client.py

```
from factory.logger import LoggerFactory
from helpers.environment import (
    get_log_level,
    get_nats_connection,
    get_nats_queue,
    get_nats_subscription_subject,
)

from client.callbacks import closed_cb, disconnected_cb, error_cb, reconnected_cb
from client.handlers import message_handler

log = LoggerFactory.get_logger(__name__, log_level=get_log_level())


class NATSClient:
    def __init__(self, nc):
        """_summary_

        Args:
            nc (_type_): _description_
        """
        self.nc = nc

    async def start(self):
        """_summary_"""
        try:
            servers = get_nats_connection()
            log.info(f"NATS client connection attempt to: {servers} ...")
            # Setting explicit callbacks and list of servers.
            await self.nc.connect(
                servers=servers,
                reconnected_cb=reconnected_cb,
                disconnected_cb=disconnected_cb,
                error_cb=error_cb,
                closed_cb=closed_cb,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f"Encountered an error connecting client to server, {e}")

        client = self.nc

        if client.is_connected:
            log.info("NATS client successfully connected to server!")

            try:
                # Subscription using a queue so that only a single subscriber
                await client.subscribe(
                    subject=get_nats_subscription_subject(),
                    queue=get_nats_queue(),
                    cb=message_handler,
                )
                json.loads(on_purpose)  # throw exception on purpose
            except Exception as e:
                log.info("Encountered error during message handling!", e)

            await client.flush(1)
```

The issue I am having is being able to, gracefully, exit out of the program if I manually press ctrl+c, and re-enter the loop for handling messages if something happens during the polling process on the NATS Queue messages are not processed, and I have to manually exit the code with ctrl+c.

I have also encountered other errors such as:

```
    Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000259F51E3550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2022-04-13 09:49:55.681 1738 default_exception_handler ERROR  Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<Client._read_loop() done, defined at \.venv\lib\site-packages\nats\aio\client.py:1908> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000259F53B0610>()]>>
2022-04-13 09:49:55.682 1738 default_exception_handler ERROR  Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<Client._ping_interval() done, defined at .venv\lib\site-packages\nats\aio\client.py:1891> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000259F5395E20>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Client._flusher at 0x00000259F53C28C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 1873, in _flusher
    future: asyncio.Future = await self._flush_queue.get()
  line 168, in get
    getter.cancel()  # Just in case getter is not done yet.
  line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2022-04-13 09:49:55.686 1738 default_exception_handler ERROR  Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-7' coro=<Client._flusher() done, defined at .venv\lib\site-packages\nats\aio\client.py:1861> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Subscription._wait_for_msgs at 0x00000259F53C24C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 271, in _wait_for_msgs
    msg = await self._pending_queue.get()
  line 168, in get
    getter.cancel()  # Just in case getter is not done yet.
  line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2022-04-13 09:49:55.689 1738 default_exception_handler ERROR  Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-8' coro=<Subscription._wait_for_msgs() done, defined at .venv\lib\site-packages\nats\aio\subscription.py:262> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated in understanding this async concept and error handling.